# Django REST app returns 502 Bad Gateway on HTTP requests containing data once hosted on GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, nginx, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I created simple Django REST app and allowed all of the hosts for CORS in my `settings.py` using:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
```

I use Postman for faking requests from client-side and one of the request I am attempting is `rest-auth/registration/` request.

When do a registration for locally hosted Django REST app all works fine and it responses with **200** but once I deploy it to GAE the following thing happens:

If I send the empty request (that is without username, password, password_confirmation) I receive normal response that the fields are mandatory, but once I add those strings to my request the response takes long time and the outcome is **502 Bad Gateway** and in my GAE logs I can only see

```
"POST /rest-auth/registration/ HTTP/1.1" 502
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:17)
```

What can be the issue here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of debugging strategies have you tried? You can log the execution of the endpoint /rest-auth/registration/  in Cloud Logging by executing printing statements after each function. Have you interacted with that url using a web browser and the developer tools to see if there are more messages thrown? I have deployed a quick django app to app engine taking as reference [1] and the CORS setting above and I did not receive 503 messages. This is why I mentioned printing the execution of the endpoint /rest-auth/registration/ to Cloud Logging.

Comment: You can use the client library[2] or simply add print(“Step1 completed”). 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#deploying_the_app_to_the_standard_environment_
[2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#using_the_python_root_logger